# Retrieving a Bitnami Solr EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, bitnami

I had been working on a Bitnami Solr Image on EC2 instance. Accidently the instance got terminated.

Is there a way I can retrieve the instance?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you had a snapshot, there is no way to recover a terminated instance.

Going forward, you may want to turn on termination protection. With that you have to turn off the protection before you can terminate it.